# File Not Found When Absolute Path Is Specified in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, io

I am trying to open a .csv file using FileReader in Eclipse.  I have tried specifying the file's absolute path (as shown below), as well as moving the file into the current directory.  Either way, I get the same I/O Exception - shown below after the code. Any help with this would be appreciated. thx

```
package demos;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSV;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReadProc;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriteProc;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class ExampleCSVWrite {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
     CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new  FileReader("/Users/aaronarpi/Documents/UA.csv"));
     List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
     reader.close();
   }


}
```

The exceptions are:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
    Unhandled exception type IOException
    Unhandled exception type IOException

at demos.ExampleCSVWrite.main(ExampleCSVWrite.java:12)
```

Comment: you have a directory called `Users` in the root of your file system? otherwise your path is wrong.

Comment: @redFIVE That would be standard for OS X.

Comment: You're not *getting* the exception, you're getting a compiler error about handling the exception.

Comment: @chrylis, Ah, I guess it would help if people mentioned their OS when talking about absolute paths

Comment: Completely irrelevant anyway, but that's pretty well-known.

Answer (score 4):

Error mentions about the uncatched IOException. You either need to throw or catch the `IOException`

```
public class ExampleCSVWrite {
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
     CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new  FileReader("/Users/aaronarpi/Documents/UA.csv"));
     List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
     reader.close();
   }
}
```